# How to disable/change a left-click selection on JTable

Tags: java, swing, jtable, border, mouseevent

I want to create a Jtable that works like in Total Comander - a row should get a dotted border after left-click selection and it should be selected after right-click.

So far I used MouseAdapter and I can select a row after right click on it, but it is also seleced if I use left click. How can I disable it or change left-click behaviour to make a row have a dotted border?

Here's my MouseAdapter:

```
public class TableMouseListener extends MouseAdapter {

    private JTable table;

    public TableMouseListener(JTable table) {
        this.table = table;
    }

    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
        if (SwingUtilities.isLeftMouseButton(e)) {

        } else if (SwingUtilities.isRightMouseButton(e)) {
            Point p = e.getPoint();
            int rowNumber = table.rowAtPoint(p);
            ListSelectionModel model = table.getSelectionModel();
            model.setSelectionInterval(rowNumber, rowNumber);
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: how did you determine if event came from [LEFT or RIGHT_MOUSE_BUTTON](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8972362/714968), for better help sooner post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/), short runnable, compilable and I'd be to use `prepareRenderer` for this job too

Comment: @mKorbel - I updated my question with my MouseAdapter

Comment: please and your Renderer is .... ?????, phaaa :-)

Comment: basically this is booking example how to use Renderer

Comment: you can't - except by going very dirty and intercept the mouseListeners that are installed by the ui-delegate

Comment: @kleopatra: Well, that is what I was afraid of, but still hoping for some kind of a easier solution.

Comment: please I disagree this is about how to store non_continius cell selection by storing this flag in XxxTableModel, solved here a few times, I think that without going dirty and intercept nor touched ui_whatever

Comment: @mKorbel don't think so: the major problem seems to be to _prevent_ selection on left mouse. Though I don't know which selection state that dotted border would be: focused, that is setting lead without setting the selection?

Comment: @kleopatra could be (I'm hope that you are) right only about to disabling

Comment: @kleopatra it should not be that difficult to do with a custom selection model which implements all the default methods by doing nothing and adding a few proprietary methods that actually implements selection. Then, in the MouseListener, you can simply implement the behaviour described above by invoking those proprietary methods.

Comment: @GuillaumePolet well, implementing models that violate their contract is not really an option in any qa controlled environment, that's even dirtier than silencing the ui-installed listeners ;) Base problem here seems to a non-standard user interaction model that can only be supported by a custom ui delegate (for each LAF)

Comment: @kleopatra I always thought that we could provide our own implementation of `ListSelectionModel` if we wanted, for example, prevent the selection of some rows. Is this not how it is supposed to be done? If not, how are we supposed to do that?

Comment: @GuillaumePolet hmm ... here you would need to disable all "normal" methods and build a complete new set of methods to do the half/-selection (or whatever the dotted border would mean) and your complete stack of client code would need to know about it. Sounds a bit extreme - or maybe I simply misunderstand what you are suggesting :-)

Comment: @Guillaume Polet `our own implementation of ListSelectionModel`, you needed to use 2D array instead, something like as to multiple setValueAt and getValueAt for mouse_events